# Summer in Saint Helena

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2012, domain-names

The Winter Bash site is located at `http://winterba.sh/`.

Only one problem:

- [`.sh` is the ccTLD for the British dependency of Saint Helena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sh).
- Saint Helena is in the *Southern Hemisphere*.
- It's *Summer* in Saint Helena.

So shouldn't it be the *Summer Bash*? Don't forget our Aussie/Kiwi/South African/Southern Brazilian/Argentine/Uruguayan/Zimbabwean/Swazi/Tokelauan/Tuvaluan/Pitcairn Islander/[Spheniscid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuFi5.png) friends!

[image: Australian slouch hat]

Comment: sh hhhhh don't tell anyone.

Comment: Are you saying the snowflakes on http://winterba.sh/ should move upwards?

Comment: (: ¡ǝɹǝɥdsıɯǝɥ uɹǝɥʇnos ǝɥʇ oʇ ollǝH

Comment: @balpha: They should also melt.

Comment: Do we have any users from Saint Helena?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can host a birthday bash for someone even if it's not *my* birthday. I don't see the problem here.

Now, if you wanted to revoke the hat privileges of users in the southern hemisphere that would make sense. Maybe in June there can be an upside-down winterbash for southern-hemisphere users, where the hat gets placed on the bottom of the avatar. Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe. But, I have two counterarguments for you:

1. Stack Overflow/Exchange is based in New York City, which is in the Northern hemisphere and is currently (theoretically) enjoying a nice, New Englandy winter.
2. There's lots of hats that are summer (or at least non-winter) themed.

Are you saying that just because it's December, we shouldn't have a Mardi Gras mask? What kind of monster are you?! (Joking!)

We tried to balance our explicitly wintry hats against thematically-appropriate ones. :)

Comment: New York is decidedly *not* New Englandy. YOU TAKE THAT BACK RIGHT NOW. Signed, a Yankees and Giants fan.

Comment: Look, @LessPop_MoreFizz, I'm from Texas. As far as I'm concerned, Maine to Virginia is "damned Yankee Land" :P

Comment: I live more at north than Long Island. For me, New York is all south land. `;)`

Comment: And those of us in Europe, if we use the word *Yankee* at all, usually mean all USAmericans.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, and the answer isn't to prevent those in the Northern Hemisphere from "enjoying" their freezing cold winter, but to localise (yes, that's how its spelled where I come from) the system so that those of us that had winter 6 months ago don't feel like the party is somewhere else.

For those of us in the Southern Hemisphere it should be a summer bash.

Comment: Of course there are those [in the middle, including some in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_climate) that have something barely recognisable as a season. What the heck you call the bash for them is anyone's guess...