# winter bash misnamed

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Summer in Saint Helena](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159388/summer-in-saint-helena)

It's 36 degrees celsius, (100 degrees Fahrenheit) here today. I'm in a city in Australia, in the Southern Hemisphere. Like some users in New Zealand, South Africa, Argentina, and Chile, I find it jarring to be offered a place in a "winter bash" in the middle of summer!

Perhaps next time the Stack Overflow team can think of a better name?

Comment: I see your 36 degrees and raise you 75 % relative humidity.

Comment: Now, are we going to destroy the myth about Christmas and snow? We should change all the pictures showing Santa Claus on his sled. `;)`